# How can I fix my accordion overlapping my footer in Shopify parallax theme?

Tags: javascript, css, shopify, accordion, footer

My Accordion is overlapping my footer when collapsed. How can I make it so that the page will expand when my accordion collapses and doesn't overlap my footer? (Shopify parallax theme)

I've tried adding display block on both footer and accordion CSS, as well as position: relative on my footer CSS but still no luck.

```
.accordion {
  background-color:white;
  color:#444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\FF0B'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
  font-size:20px;
}

''''

 .footer {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: {{ settings.sub_footer_color }};
    color: {{ settings.sub_footer_text_color }};
    {% if settings.custom_footer %}
      background-image: url("{{ settings.custom_footer | img_url: '2000x' }}");
      {% if settings.footer_bg_stretched %}
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
      {% else %}
        background-repeat:{{ settings.footer_repeat_bg }};
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
        }

''''

<div id="navigation">
<input type="hidden" name="demo2" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
    to highlight the button that controls the panel */
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question for faster response - Welcome to StackOverflow - make sure you take the [tour]

Comment: have you considered using the `margin-top` attribute of your `.footer` class to act as a buffer?

Comment: I just tried adding margin-top:50px but yet still no luck my accordion keeps overlapping footer.